# Eclipse CDT / GDB - open core dump?

Tags: eclipse, gdb

With Eclipse it is possible to run a process through gdb.

This gives us a pretty GUI which can be used to inspect the call stack, variable contents etc.

Is it possible to open a core dump in Eclipse and inspect it through gdb?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After switching to the Debug perspective, select **Run** -> **Debug Configurations...** (scroll down if you don't see it) -> **C/C++ Postmortem Debugger**. Then fill in the **C/C++ Application** and **Core file** fields with your executable and coredump and hit the **Debug** button.

Even though there is a logic to their menu organization, the Eclipse CDT developers sure don't make finding the most used operations easy.

Comment: Works for me with Eclipse Neon.

For cross building, you may also need to set the GDB binary to use on the *Debugger* tab.

On the *Main* tab, set the _Core file_ field to, say, `${workspace_loc}` to be prompted for the core to be used.